# jGIT Detect Conflicts by Commit&Push and Pull

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, jgit, merge-conflict-resolution

Beside merging branches, GIT can have conflicts by

- Commit/Push ( if a file in GIT has been modified meanwhile
- by Pull, if the local file has been modified by me.

How can I list this conflicts before the push or pull and mark them as fixed?

I tried using Git.status(), and expected to see this files under conflicts, but nothing is listed.

```
Status status = git.status().call();
status.getConflicting();
```

Here are some code snippets I use:

```
git.pull().setContentMergeStrategy(ContentMergeStrategy.CONFLICT).setCredentialsProvider( new FxGitCredentialsProvider( getDialogScene() )).call();
```

```
final AddCommand addCommand = git.add();
for ( String filePattern : filePatterns){
    addCommand.addFilepattern( filePattern );
}
addCommand.call();

git.commit().setMessage(messageTextArea.getText()).setCredentialsProvider( new FxGitCredentialsProvider( getDialogScene() )).call();
if ( push ){
   PushCommand pushCommand = git.push().setCredentialsProvider( new FxGitCredentialsProvider( getDialogScene()));
   pushCommand.call();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two clarifications :

1. `git push` doesn't trigger *conflicts* (not a file level conflict as a `merge` would do), it just refuses to update a branch if the commit you are pushing is not a fast forward of the existing branch tip
2. `git pull` is actually a 2 steps command : `git fetch`, which recovers the commits from the remote repository, followed by `git merge <upstream branch>`
   conflicts may be triggered by the second step (a regular `git merge`)

There *are* other commands that may trigger conflicts: `git cherry-pick` and `git rebase`

---

To fix issues with `1.`: you won't see anything by running `git status`, you should update your view of the remote (`git fetch`), inspect the history and select what to do:

- probably run `git merge <upstream/branch>` or `git rebase <upstream/branch>`.
  As said above: running `git fetch` followed by `git merge` is the same as running `git pull`, the difference is that you can *inspect the state of your repo* before running `git merge`.
- or force push : `git push --force-with-lease origin`

To fix issues with `2.`: you can run a regular merge conflict resolution.

Comment: Thank you.  I changed my code, and for a pull I do this sequence:

Comment: @DbSchema could you please elaborate what was your solution here? and share updated snippets?